# Maintaining session by rewriting URL

Tags: session, cookies, url-rewriting, http-streaming

I'm developing a JavaScript library supporting HTTP Streaming and WebSocket, [jQuery Stream](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-stream/) . I used XDomainRequest to perform HTTP Streaming when user's browser is IE8+, but there is one problem.

The problem is that user's session is not maintained and newly generated session is provided instead, because XDomainRequest excludes cookies when sending data to the server. Anyway, finally I found that it can be solved by rewriting URL.

So, I want to know **how to rewrite URL to maintain user session** in popular server-side technology such as .NET, PHP, Python and Ruby.

For example, in Java Servlet

```
/event-stream // by cookies
/event-stream;jsessionid=(The value of JSESSIONID contained in cookies) // by rewriting URL
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Java**

```
/event-stream
/event-stream;jsessionid=(The value of JSESSIONID contained in cookies)
```

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagm.html

**PHP**

```
/event-stream
/event-stream?PHPSESSID=(The value of PHPSESSID contained in cookies)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

**ASP.NET**

```
/(app name)/event-stream
/(app name)/(S(The value of ASP.NET_SessionId contained in cookies))/event-stream/
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx

**Ruby on Rails** and **Django** don't allow you to pass the session id!

The IE Team said that there are no plans to change this behavior (sending cookies).